# Why this exception "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" in Entity Framework core occured?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have simple Forum application that each topic has many post, and each post may liked by several users. application Entity Models are as following:

```
public class ForumTopic
{
    public int ForumTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ForumPost> ForumPosts { get; set; }
}

public class ForumPost
{
    public int ForumPostId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int ForumTopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual ForumTopic ForumTopic { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ForumPostFavorite> ForumPostFavorites { get; set; }
}

public class ForumPostFavorite
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int ForumPostId { get; set; }
    public ForumPost ForumPost { get; set; }
}
```

I want take current user favorite posts as following. but this query throws "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" Exception. I am sure that this query run in entity framework 6 without exception, but in Entity Framework core this exception occurs.

```
public IActionResult Favorite()
{
    var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

    var list =  _dbContext.ForumPostFavorites
        .Where(e => e.UserId == userId)
        .Select(e => e.ForumPost)
        .Take(10)
        .Select(e => new ForumPostFavoriteVm
        {
            ForumPostId = e.ForumPostId,
            ForumTopicId = e.ForumTopicId,
            Message = e.Message,
            Subject = e.ForumTopic.Subject,
        }).ToList();

    return View(list);
}
```

When I remove this line **"Subject = e.ForumTopic.Subject"** from query, the query runs without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put Skip() & Take() after projection:

```
 var list =  _dbContext.ForumPostFavorites
    .Where(e => e.UserId == userId)
    .Select(e => e.ForumPost)
    .Select(e => new ForumPostFavoriteVm
    {
        ForumPostId = e.ForumPostId,
        ForumTopicId = e.ForumTopicId,
        Message = e.Message,
        Subject = e.ForumTopic.Subject,
    })
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```